# How to print the data of each cluster in agglomerative clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I'm new in machine learning tool in python, I write this code of agglomerative hierarchical clustering but I don't know if any way to print the data of each plot cluster.
the input of algorithm is 5 numbers(0,1,2,3,4),In addition to drawing clusters, I need to print the value of each cluster separately something like this 
cluster1= [1,2,4] 
cluster2=[0,3]

**update:** I want to get the data that is drew and colored according to this line and other lines `plt.scatter(points[y_hc==0,0], points[y_hc==0,1],s=100,c='cyan')`, according to this code these numbers(1,2,4) are in one cluster and have the same color and (0,3) are in cluster2, so, I need to print these data(the data of each cluster) in terminal. this code is just drawing data.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
dataset= make_blobs(n_samples=5, n_features=2,centers=4, cluster_std=1.6, random_state=50)
points= dataset[0]

import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch 
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(points,method='ward'))
plt.scatter(dataset[0][:,0],dataset[0][:,1])
hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=4, affinity='euclidean',linkage='ward')
y_hc= hc.fit_predict(points)
plt.scatter(points[y_hc==0,0], points[y_hc==0,1],s=100,c='cyan')
plt.scatter(points[y_hc==1,0], points[y_hc==1,1],s=100,c='yellow')
plt.scatter(points[y_hc==2,0], points[y_hc==2,1],s=100,c='red')
plt.scatter(points[y_hc==3,0], points[y_hc==3,1],s=100,c='green')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve.  What is the problem your encountering?  With the code you've posted, you won't see all of the plots because you only call `plt.show()` once at the end.  When I run your code (thanks for including a reproducible example, by the way!) I get scatter plots which seem to correspond correctly to the predictions in `y_hc`.  You can get a similar result more succinctly using `plt.scatter(dataset[0][:, 0], dataset[0][:, 1], c=y_hc);`.

Comment: This code is just clustering the input values (5 numbers) in dendrogram, as you saw when run the code, so, I need to print in terminal the values that refer for each cluster.

Comment: In dendrogram the values(0,3) is refer to cluster 
and (2.1,4) refer to other cluster, so, I need to get this valuers and printing in terminal

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm being a bit slow.  Do you mean to match the values in `dataset[1]` to the clusters in the `dendrogram` variable (`dict`)?

Comment: I need to save the values of each cluster that shown in dendrogram  in array or anything and then print them

Comment: the output is something like this  c1=(0,3)  c2=(2,1,4),

Answer (score 1):

Having done some research it seems that there isn't an easy way to get the cluster labels from `scipy`'s `dendrogram` function.

Below are a couple of options/workarounds.

## Option One

Use `scipy`'s `linkage` and `fcluster` functions to perform the clustering and get the labels:

```
Z = sch.linkage(points, 'ward') # Note 'ward' is specified here to match the linkage used in sch.dendrogram.
labels = sch.fcluster(Z, t=10, criterion='distance') # t chosen to return two clusters.

# Cluster 1
np.where(labels == 1)
```

Outputs: `(array([0, 3]),)`

```
# Cluster 2
np.where(labels == 2)
```

Outputs: `(array([1, 2, 4]),)`

## Option Two

Modify your current use of `sklearn` to return two clusters:

```
hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='euclidean',linkage='ward') # Again, 'ward' is specified here to match the linkage in sch.dendrogram.
y_hc = hc.fit_predict(points)

# Cluster 1
np.where(y_hc == 0)
```

Outputs: `(array([0, 3]),)`

```
# Cluster 2
np.where(y_hc == 1)
```

Outputs: `(array([1, 2, 4]),)`